# How should I support rectangular duct in wall?

Tags: hvac

In California, I'm installing a 3x14 rectangular supply duct from my attic to my first floor. It goes vertically through the second floor wall, through the floor, and ends in the first floor ceiling.

How should I support the duct run in the wall cavity?

Comment: Hard to say with any specificity, not being able to see the duct assembly or your framing. You might add photos.

Comment: @isherwood it's a standard 16" OC interior wall stud bay that I'm putting a duct down through. What sort of picture would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I usually shoot a couple of screws through the sheet metal into the studs, if you have AC I like a layer of insulation to prevent sweating and dry rot potential, but have not really seen any problems when directly attached with no insulation verticly in a wall.

Comment: I want sure if I was allowed by code to just drill through the duct into the stud